# how to debian downgrade autoconf?

Tags: debian, autoconf, autoreconf

short of compiling the old package, is there an elegant way to downgrade the autoconf package. During cilkplus-gcc compile, I got:

```
aclocal.m4:16: warning: this file was generated for autoconf 2.64.
You have another version of autoconf.  It may work, but is not guaranteed to.
If you have problems, you may need to regenerate the build system entirely.
To do so, use the procedure documented by the package, typically `autoreconf'.
configure.ac:24: error: Please use exactly Autoconf 2.64 instead of 2.69
```

Answer (score 0):

this is specific to cilkplus-gcc; works with autoconf 2.69 and following 2 changes to cilkplus-gcc svn version 236689:
basically change 2.64 to 2.69 in following files:
config/override.m4

```
m4_ifndef([_GCC_AUTOCONF_VERSION],
-  [m4_define([_GCC_AUTOCONF_VERSION], [2.64])])
+  [m4_define([_GCC_AUTOCONF_VERSION], [2.69])])
```

libcilkrts/configure.ac

```
 AC_INIT([Cilk Runtime Library], [2.0], [cilk@intel.com])
 -AC_PREREQ([2.64])
 +AC_PREREQ([2.69])
```